# Scipy: Sparse Matrix to ndarray

Tags: scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I have a matrix A in CSC-format, of which I index just a single column

```
b = A[:,col]
```

resulting in a (n x 1) matrix. What I want to do is:

```
v  = M * b
```

where M is a (n x n) matrix in CSR. The result v is a (n x 1) CSR-matrix. I need to iterate the values in v (not including the 0s actually) and retrieve the index of one element meeting a special criteria (note: sparse matrix formats were not chosen to fit that particular operation, but general matrix x matrix-products should be fastest with CSR * CSC, right?)

The problem is, that iterating the entries in the CSR-formatted vector (0 < i < n: v[i,0]) is terribly slow and I actually waste quite some memory since v is not sparse anymore.

Could anyone tell me how to perform these operations as such, that I can quickly iterate over the result vector, keeping the copy-related memory overhead small?

```
IN: M (CSR-Matrix), A (CSC-Matrix), col_index
v = M * A[:,col_index]
for entries in v:
    do stuff
```

Is it also possible to somehow speed up "advanced" indexing over columns in a CSC-Matrix? At some other point in the code, I have to extract a submatrix of A (cannot be reformulated to allow for slicing, therefore using an index array), that includes a given subset of all columns. A[:,idxlist] takes quite long when line-profiling.

Looking forward to your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scipy sparse module is getting better every release, but it is quite obviously work in progress, so there is a lot of optimization you can do by accessing the innards of the objects directly. E.g. your case:

```
>>> a = sps.rand(5, 20, density=0.2, format='csr')
>>> b = sps.rand(20, 1, density=0.2, format='csc')
>>> c = a * b
>>> c.A
array([[ 0.30331594],
       [ 0.        ],
       [ 0.12198742],
       [ 0.34350077],
       [ 0.        ]])
```

You can get the non-zero entries of `c` as `c.data`:

```
>>> c.data
array([ 0.30331594,  0.12198742,  0.34350077])
```

Getting the corresponding row number is a little trickier. Probably the easiest would be to convert your output to CSC format, since them you have them directly as `c.indices`, and `c.data` will still be the same as before:

```
>>> c.tocsc().indices
array([0, 2, 3])
>>> c.tocsc().data
array([ 0.30331594,  0.12198742,  0.34350077])
```

But you can extract them without doing the conversion if you don't fancy it:

```
>>> np.where(c.indptr[:-1] != c.indptr[1:])[0]
array([0, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

So if you wanted to find, e.g. the largest value and its row number, you could do:

```
>>> row_idx = np.where(c.indptr[:-1] != c.indptr[1:])[0]
>>> idx = np.argmax(c.data)
>>> c.data[idx], row_idx[idx]
(0.34350077450601624, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you. For now I ended up changing M to a CSC-matrix. Benchmarking with considerably big matrices did not really show any particular slowdown in the code due to the conversion (CSC * CSC matrix mult instead of CSR * CSC).
However, as a nice side effect I get all the non-zero indices in the indices array straight away, just like you said :)

Answer (score 1):

In a Code Review problem I am exploring ways of speeding up the iteration over the rows of a sparse matrix, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32664/numpy-scipy-optimization/33566#33566

`csr` `getrow` is surprisingly slow.  At least for that small test case it is faster to convert the sparse matrix to a dense array, and use regular numpy indexing (use `np.nonzero` to get sparse entries). It is equally fast to convert the matrix to `lil`, and do regular Python iteration on `zip(X.data, X.rows)`.

My impression is that `scipy.sparse` is best for linear algebra problems, and slow for indexing and iteration.